# Unable to enter recovery mode for Marshmallow manual OTA update on Nexus 6

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, ota-update, motorola-nexus-6

I am sharing this piece of knowledge for the folks who might face the same problem.

### Scenario

I am manually upgrading a rooted Motorola Nexus 6 device, for which OTA update is not available due to system ROM modification. A populare guide can be found [here](http://www.androidexplained.com/nexus-6-sideload-android-6-0-1-marshmallow/) or by following [Nexus Root Toolkit's](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) wizard.

### Problem

Android reboots in recovery mode with a "No command" message. NRT and guides say that this is the pre-screen to recovery. I need to enter recovery and enable download from ADB. The problem is that when I do the <kbd>PWR</kbd>+<kbd>Volume+</kbd> sequence I only get the device rebooted into Android

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

First press the <kbd>PWR</kbd> button, then quickly press once the <kbd>Volume+</kbd> button and **release** the keys.

### Explanation

It could be tricky for some people to enter the combination right.

Nexus 6 does not allow direct Recovery boot using <kbd>PWR</kbd>+<kbd>Volume+</kbd> combo on powered off phone. Instead, you have to go through the bootloader.

Once you are in the recovery pre-screen (in my case, of ROM `MOB30O`), holding the <kbd>PWR</kbd> button will force the device's power cycle. If you press <kbd>Volume+</kbd> before <kbd>PWR</kbd>, recovery will ignore the sequence, and then if you hold <kbd>PWR</kbd> a power cycle will start.

The power cycle then will simply ignore that you are holding <kbd>Volume+</kbd> button, bringing you to Android OS with a normal boot